# Need help with polynomial factorisation problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Problem: $a, b, c$ are distinct real numbers and there are real numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $a^3 + ax + y = 0$, $b^3 + bx + y = 0$ and $c^3 + cx + y = 0$. Show that $a + b + c = 0$.

Comment: If you instead asked "What is $a+b+c$?", depending on the mathematics needed to solve it, it might fit right into a high school competition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $a,b $ and $c $ are roots of $X^3+xX+y=0$, which we can therefore factorise as $(X-a)(X-b)(X-c)=0$. If we expand this back out, the coefficients must equal the original ones. What does the coefficient of $X^2$ tell us?

Note: the formulas that arise from this idea are known as Vieta's formulas. The level that these are introduced gives the level of the problem, but in principle a particularly bright student could hit on the idea with only knowledge of polynomials and factorisation.